# Textfield height seems to be smaller than combobox height using ext js

Tags: css, extjs

I have a combobox which is placed next to textfield using column layout in an panel. Textfield height seems to be smaller than combobox height using ext js.How to resolve this height issue between combobox and textfield ?

my code:

```
 var myText = new Ext.form.TextField({
                             //readOnly: true,
                             id:"IdKey"+i,
                             //layout: 'vbox',
                             //align:'stretch',
                             //width: 140,
                             border: 1,
                             style: {
                                 borderColor: 'black',
                                 borderStyle: 'solid'
                             },
                             //fieldLabel: myData[i].name,
                             value: jsonItems[i].G3E_USERNAME,


                         });
                         panelItems.push(myText);
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                     id: "IdValue" + i,
                                     triggerAction: 'all',
                                     allowBlank: isReq ? false : true,
                                     editable: false,
                                     //forceSelection : true,
                                     store : pickStore,
                                     //width: 140,
                                     //width:Ext.getCmp('windowId').getInnerWidth()/2,
                                     //border: 1,
                                     displayField: 'ATTRIBUTEPNOVALUE',
                                     valueField : 'ATTRIBUTEPNOVALUE',
                                     //style: {
                                     //    borderColor: 'black',
                                     //    borderStyle: 'solid'
                                     //},
                                     //value: jsonItems[i].ATTRIBUTE_TEXT,
                                     mode: 'local',
});
panelItems.push(combo );
```

FormPanel:

```
var SwitchPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                         id: 'switchPanelId',
                         layout: 'column',
                         monitorValid : true,
                         //width: Ext.getCmp('windowId').width,
                         width: 290,

                         autoHeight: true,

                         items: panelItems,
                         buttons: [
                             {
                             //monitorValid: true,
                                 text: 'save',
                                 handler: function () {
                                     alert('submit..'+allChangedItems.length);
                                     SwitchPanel.getForm().submit({

                                             //url: 'submit.php'
                                         });

                                 }


                         }]
                     })
```

In this way im adding the combo and textfields on satisfying some condition.Width im appending dynamically to the elements. PanelItems are used in the formpanel.But textfield and combobox are not having the same height. How can i resolve this. 
Thanks.

Comment: can u show us some code?

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Ya i have included the code

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that i see there, that could cause a difference in the height of the components, is the different style and border applied to them. I think that just uncommenting the border and the style of the combo, should work. Something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i5m

Comment: I have included the style but it didnt workout so i have uncommented. this didnt help.How can i resolve , is there any other way?

Comment: Try to inspect the style of that elements with firebug. Maybe some style is being applied to one of the components. Check for borders, margins, paddings or height.

Comment: When there is textbox beside texbox there is no difference in heights. But textbox and combobox this variation is seen. During inspection im able to apply the padding style to match the height but through code it is not appending the style. But it should not be height difference issue ,how can i resolve this